# Looking for an idiom similar to 'pros and cons' but with different meaning

Tags: idioms

I'm writing an essay where where the protagonist faces betrayal & hurt etc (negative things) but along with that she also experiences compassion & affection (Positive things). All the emotions at the hands of different people, so I want an idiom or a saying (if one exists) which u know explains that 'Where there is bad, there is also good' or 'When bad happens, good also keeps happening simultaneously' or something like that! I'm sorry if I failed to explain u clearly, but my English is not really good because it is not my native language!

Thanks in advance..

Comment: As my old Norfolk uncle, long since passed away, used to say 'things will have to get better soon because of the law of averages'. For old-boy Henry everything, including the weather, worked according to 'the law of averages'.

Comment: 'Life has its ups and downs' is almost a dead metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for...

> ***Every cloud has a silver lining***
>   (Gradually refined over the centuries, starting from [John Milton, *Comus*, 1634](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/every-cloud-has-a-silver-lining.html))

That's the "pro" way of looking at things. For the "con" side [(glass half-empty, not half-full)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is_the_glass_half_empty_or_half_full?), you could go for a whimsical reversal *(Every silver lining has a cloud)*, or...

> ***Into every life a little rain must fall***
>   (or [variants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Into_Each_Life_Some_Rain_Must_Fall) thereof)